# Calculation in jsp table for each row

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I have a table in jsp which have 3 columns- num1, num2, sum

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Number1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Number2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Sum
        </td>
    </tr>

    <s:iterator value="transactionList"  var="row" status="status" >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <s:textfield name = "num1" id="num1" onblur="fnSum();" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <s:textfield name = "num2" id="num2" onblur="fnSum();" readonly="true" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <s:textfield name = "sum" id="sum" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fnSum()
    {
        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        var total = num1 + num2;
        document.getElementById("sum").value = total;
    }
    </script>
```

I want to display the sum automatically for each of the row. Above code works only for the first row, but not for the other rows. I am not sure how to DO that. Thanks in advance

Comment: html id should be unique, you are printing for only one id "sum" document.getElementById("sum").value = total;

Comment: thanks Ramesh, can you please tell me how to make these ids unique so that the sum is calculated for each row

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramesh stated, you are using same ID on each row, that is your problem. You need to generate dynamically IDs depending on each row. One way doing it is by using the `status` attribute from `<s:iterator />`.

Also, your JavaScript code have hardcoded IDs, so event with right IDs in the table, that wont work. Here is the solution for you :

```
<s:iterator value="transactionList" var="row" status="status" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="row%{#status.count}-num1" id="row%{#status.count}-num1" onblur="fnSum('row%{#status.count}');" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="row%{#status.count}-num2" id="row%{#status.count}-num2" onblur="fnSum('row%{#status.count}');" readonly="true" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <s:textfield name="row%{#status.count}-sum" id="row%{#status.count}-sum" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function fnSum(row)
    {
        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById(row + "-num1").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById(row + "-num2").value);
        var total = num1 + num2;
        document.getElementById(row + "-sum").value = total;
    }
</script>
```

Note : this code has not been tested since I don't use Struts. Also wondering why you are not displaying any values from the `var="row"` ?

Comment: @NitumoniDas I've searched a bit and now it should work, but unfortunately I don't have a ready setup to test it.